# Can't add a dynamic feature module because of build flavor problems

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, dynamic-feature

I wanted to implement a new dynamic feature module in an existing app but had to give up due to product flavor problems.

The example code can be found here. https://github.com/henningBunk/dynamic_feature_problem

I have three modules:

1. app. The main module of the app. It has two product flavors:

`store`: `amazon` and `google`
`pay_status`: `free` and `pro`

Resulting in four combinations:
`amazonFree`, `amazonPro`, `googleFree` and `googlePro`

It depends on `lib` and lists `dynamic_feature` as a dynamic feature.

2. lib. A library module, `app` and `dynamic_feature` depend on this module. `lib` only has the `pay_status` flavor. So when I build eg. the App as the `googleFree` flavor, lib will build it's `free` flavor.
3. dynamic_feature. The new feature which shall be a dynmic feature. This module should not have any flavors. It depends on app and lib.

The three gradle files, reduced to product flavors and dependecies look like this:

App module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    dynamicFeatures = [":faq"]

    flavorDimensions "store", "pay_status"

    productFlavors {
        google { dimension "store" }
        amazon { dimension "store" }

        free { dimension "pay_status" }
        pro { dimension "pay_status" }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':lib')
}
```

Lib module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    flavorDimensions "pay_status"

    productFlavors {
        free { dimension "pay_status" }
        pro { dimension "pay_status" }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

Dynamic feature module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'

android {}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':app')
    implementation project(':lib')
}
```

This results in the error:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':dynamic_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app.
Show Details
Affected Modules: dynamic_feature
```

So I read that the module `dynamic_feature` might need a missing dimension strategy. Adding

```
missingDimensionStrategy "store", "google"
missingDimensionStrategy "pay_status", "free"
```

to the dynamic_feature build.gradle into android.defaultConfig. This way I can build some flavors but not all of them:

[image]

Comment: Hi had the same issue and in my case I simply forgot to replace `apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'` with `apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'` in one module.... 

Comment: are you sure that we have the same problem? since i am already using ''com.android.dynamic-feature''. my problem lies in the different build variants.

Comment: Pretty sure... Maybe there is more than one way to get this error.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution but it's not satisfying. All build flavors must be implemented in the dynamic feature modul so all build flavors can actually be built.

`missingDimensionStrategy` does not work.

more infos here: https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-4-a-new-version-fc2ad80c01bb